# hyperledger composer-cli on multi host

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to configure hyperledger fabric composer on multiple host using swarm. I have one peer instantiated on one pc and another peer on another. They have both joined the channel and can communicate with each other. I am using the following guide for help:

https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

I have put the peer ports and the IPs of the PC in connection.json file as follows:

```
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053"
    },
    "peer1.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://10.128.0.12:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://10.128.0.12:7053"
    }
```

The error I am facing is this:

```
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: 
Connect Failed
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: 
Connect Failed
```

This happens at the following line:

```
composer network install -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -a tutorial- 
network@0.0.1.bna
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the error *Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: * usually means that the business network card (via connection.json) can't find the Fabric on the addresses specified for the URLs in the connection.json file. Have you run the fabric samples to test the network? Are all your Fabric nodes started/running? and then ask if the Addresses specified in the connection.json are resolvable and accessible? Are you using docker or `docker-machine` for your network? Are you using Mac or Linux or ?

Answer (score 0):

For peer0 try putting port 8051 and event 8053. Peer1 port 9051 event 9053.